# Does anyone know why is my code not reading file from first line

Tags: c++, ifstream

I want to create program for delaying subtitles and when I run this code below is not reading from first line.
It strat like of middle of file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "fstream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     ifstream input; //input

     char input_file[32]; //names of input and output


      cout << "Enter name of input fille: "; ///user gives names of input
      cin >> input_file;

input.open(input_file);
if (!input.good()){
    cout << "File " << input_file << " dosen't exist." << endl;
    return 1;
}


string row;
while (!input.eof()){    
    getline(input, row);

    cout << row << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Must Read :[_Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong ?_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1870232)

Comment: Why `getline(input, row)`? What's wrong with `input>>row`?

Comment: BTW that code works just fine.

Comment: @barakmanos `std::getline` will read an entire line including white space. `input >> row ` won't, by default

Comment: And show the file content.

Answer (score 0):

First, `eof()` should not be placed in a `while()`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1870232) for details. So change

```
while (!input.eof()){    
    getline(input, row);
    cout << row << endl;
}
```

to

```
while (getline(input, row)){       
    cout << row << endl;
}
```

and see how it goes. It's really weird reading from the middle of the file. Maybe you can further share the content of the file to us to better fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You still can set the position to the beginning manually with `input.seekg(0, input.beg)` before reading anything.